# Qt: Changing qmake version for certain subprojects

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have a Qt project that is using the `subdirs` template. The directory architecture looks like:

```
project/
    |---project.pro
    |---sub_project_1/
    |         |---sub_project_1.pro
    |         |---main.cpp
    |         |---sub_project_1.cpp
    |         |---sub_project_1.hpp
    |---sub_project_2/
    |         |---sub_project_2.pro
    |         |---main.cpp
    |         |---sub_project_2.cpp
    |         |---sub_project_2.hpp
    |---sub_project_3/
    |         |---sub_project_3.pro
    |         |---main.cpp
    |         |---sub_project_3.cpp
    |         |---sub_project_3.hpp
    |---common/
    |         |---common.pri
    |         |---common_1.hpp
    |         |---common_2.cpp
    |         |---common_2.hpp
```

All of the sub-projects utilize classes from common. sub_project_1 and sub_project_2 are build using one Qt version, suppose 5.10.1; the latest release. Now, sub_project_3 suppose sub_project_3 must be build with Qt 5.5.1. Is there a way to keep this current architecture, and programmatically change which qmake is used build the each sub-project?

Comment: My guess is that you need to insert one more project in between of "new QMake" project and "old QMake" project and specify the environment variable `QMAKEPATH` in there. So that the right QMake is picking up the project. But anyway it all sounds fishy unless there is no binary dependency between projects. Or it may not work after all.

Comment: Combining items (except possibly carefully written plugins) built on two different version of Qt seems very dangerous, if not impossible.  What factors are keeping everything from being built on the same Qt version?

Comment: sub_project_1 and sub_project_2 are major components of the main application, while sub_project_3 is an plugin for a third party application, which only links against a different version of Qt. So I was hoping to keep the main application the latest version of Qt, while making sub_project_3 an older version to make it compatible with the third party software.